# Why are trigger pseudorecords placeholders for bind variables in trigger body but not WHEN?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/appdev.11203/e17126/triggers.htm) states that:

> In the trigger_body of a simple trigger or the tps_body of a compound trigger, a correlation name is a placeholder for a bind variable. Reference the field of a pseudorecord with this syntax:
>
> :pseudorecord_name.field_name
>
> In the WHEN clause of a conditional trigger, a correlation name is not a placeholder for a bind variable. Therefore, omit the colon in the preceding syntax.

My working example looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER started
BEFORE UPDATE OF mgr_start_date ON department
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.mgr_start_date < old.mgr_start_date)
BEGIN
    :new.mgr_start_date := :old.mgr_start_date;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rejected backdate of mgr_start_date.');
END;
```

Why are the pseudorecords (correlation names) placeholders for bind variables in one case and not the other?

Comment: You would have to ask the creators of Oracle that question.

Comment: Would the creators of Oracle care to chime in? @OldProgrammer

Comment: `:bindvar` is PL/SQL syntax, not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Would the creators of Oracle care to chime in?"

I'm not one of the creators, but I'll chime in anyway.

These pseudorecord references are not placeholders for bind variables ...

```
WHEN (new.mgr_start_date < old.mgr_start_date)
```

... because this line is part of the specification of the trigger. It's defining the condition on which the trigger fire. It's specifying the field names not values.

These pseudorecord references are placeholders ...

```
:new.mgr_start_date := :old.mgr_start_date;
```

... because they are referencing **the actual values** from the old and new versions of the record.